# Terraform depends_on local_file

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am generating json file with `local_file` and them uploading the file to `s3 bucket`.
The problem I am facing is that the config.json is not uploaded. I assume it is because at the time of generating plan the file does not exist yet.

How can I set such dependency to be uploaded in a single execution?

```
resource "local_file" "app_config" {
  filename = "../frontend/build/config.json"
  content  = jsonencode(local.config)
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "upload_object" {
  for_each     = fileset(local.build_dir, "**")
  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key          = each.value
  source       = "${local.build_dir}${each.value}"
  content_type = lookup(local.content_types, element(split(".", each.value), length(split(".", each.value)) - 1), "text/plain")
  etag         = filemd5("${local.build_dir}${each.value}")
  depends_on = [ local_file.app_config ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find solution. I do not need to create a local json file.
It is possible to upload json directly

See example below:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "upload_config" {
  bucket       = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key          = "config.json"
  content      = jsonencode(local.config)
  content_type = "application/json"
}
```